# Azure SQL Elastic Jobs & Data Tier Application (DACPAC)

Tags: azure-sql-database, devops

I'm trying to get a DACPAC containing schema changes deployed to a target group in an elastic jobs setup in Azure. I've done the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-powershell#create-required-resources) and my test jobs are executing properly. Now I want to run a DACPAC against my target group but I'm starting to realize that the documentation is for an older PowerShell module, [ElasticDatabaseJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/elasticdatabasejobs/?view=azureelasticdbjobsps-0.8.33), specifically the [Set-AzureSqlJobContentDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/elasticdatabasejobs/set-azuresqljobcontentdefinition?view=azureelasticdbjobsps-0.8.33) command. I don't see any analogous command in the [Az.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-3.5.0) documentation, nor do I see any mention of it on the [T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-tsql#main) tutorial.

What is the current way to associate a DACPAC file with an Elastic Job? Is this being phased out? Should I use the old PowerShell module? Am I missing something? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Azure hosted version of Elastic Database Jobs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-job-automation-overview#elastic-database-jobs-preview) does not support DACPAC. It is not a tested/supported scenario. Please use Powershell/T-SQL scripts for your jobs.

thanks
-- Srini Acharya

Comment: Thank you Srini. I'm curious, is this on the road map?

Comment: No, it is not in our road map at this point. If there is substantial demand, we will definitely look into this.

Comment: Thank you for your time Srini. We'll figure out another solution without DACPAC deployment & Elastic Jobs.